# JavaScript/HTML canvas: clearing a text box

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've been trying to create an interactive map with Adobe Flash CC through the HTML5 canvas. The main idea: you mouseOver an object on the map, a textbox with the according info appears on the right. The thing is, I've managed to create a textbox, but every time I mouseover the text box appears over and over again on the top and the text is getting fatter each time. How could I remove the text before adding it each time ? Maybe you have other suggestions ? 
Here's the code:

```
function makeText(x, y, w, h, htmlText) {
// create and populate element
stage.removeChild(content);
stage.update();
var e = document.createElement("div");
e.style.fontSize = "14px";
e.style.fontFamily = "arial, verdana, sans-serif";
e.style.visibility = "hidden";
e.style.position = "absolute";
e.style.left = 0;
e.style.top = 0;
e.style.width = w + "px";
e.style.height = h + "px";
e.style.overflow = "auto";
e.style.overflowX = "hidden";
e.innerHTML = htmlText;

document.body.appendChild(e);
var content = new createjs.DOMElement(e);
content.x = x;
content.y = y;

return stage.addChild(content);
}
```

And here's how I call the function:

```
  function fl_MouseOverHandler_5(){
    var canvas; 
    var text;
    var count = 0; 
 var kauno_pr = "text";
makeText(400,300,200,200,kauno_pr);   
}
```

I've also tried adding stage.removeChild(content); before adding it, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any help appreciated !

Comment: You want to clear your div or delete it ?

Comment: you are creating a div not textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
var previousElement;
function fl_MouseOverHandler_5(){
    var canvas; 
    var text;
    var count = 0; 
    var kauno_pr = "text";

    if(previousElement){
        stage.removeChild(previousElement);
    }

    previousElement = makeText(400,300,200,200,kauno_pr);   
}
```

You simply need to store the created element in a variable.